# Using GDAL to get vertices of a multipolygon

Tags: gdal, polygon, .net

I am successfully using GDAL to get the vertices of a polygon from a ShapeFile using .NET code.  This link showed me how to do that:

http://geoinformaticstutorial.blogspot.com/2012/10/accessing-vertices-from-polygon-with.html

However if the shape type is a multipolygon, then this process does not get any vertices.  How can I get the vertices of a multipolygon?

Comment: You can get the number of polygons with `getNumGeometries()` and get each polygon with `getGeometryRef(i)`.

Comment: and then follow the example for each *part* in the polygon. Polylines can also do the same if they have multiple parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used to get this to work.  This is VB.NET code:

```
Public Function SchoolDistrictBoundary() As List(Of List(Of Coordinate))
Dim district As Feature = schoolDistrict()
Dim result = New List(Of List(Of Coordinate))

If district IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim geometry = district.GetGeometryRef()
  Dim type = geometry.GetGeometryType()

  If type = wkbGeometryType.wkbPolygon Then
    'only one polygon
    Dim coordSet = New List(Of Coordinate)
    Dim ring = geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
    For x = 0 To ring.GetPointCount() - 1
      Dim point() As Double = {0, 0}
      ring.GetPoint(x, point)

      Dim coord = New Coordinate()
      coord.Longitude = point(0)
      coord.Latitude = point(1)
      coordSet.Add(coord)
    Next
    result.Add(coordSet)

  ElseIf type = wkbGeometryType.wkbMultiPolygon Then
    'multiple polygons
    Dim boundaries = geometry.GetBoundary()
    For shape = 0 To boundaries.GetGeometryCount() - 1
      Dim coordSet = New List(Of Coordinate)
      Dim polygon = boundaries.GetGeometryRef(shape)
      For x = 0 To polygon.GetPointCount() - 1
        Dim point() As Double = {0, 0}
        polygon.GetPoint(x, point)

        Dim coord = New Coordinate()
        coord.Longitude = point(0)
        coord.Latitude = point(1)

        coordSet.Add(coord)
      Next

      result.Add(coordSet)
    Next

  End If
End If
Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are happy with your script but you may find use for the Spatialite SQL dialect in the future.

Let's take a shapefile with one multipolygon to start with.

```
ogrinfo multipolygon.shp -al
INFO: Open of `multipolygon.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: multipolygon
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (403784.354400, 6924130.250945) - (409732.186830, 6926861.991572)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
OGRFeature(multipolygon):0
  MULTIPOLYGON (((403784.35439963144 6926261.3961154055,405838.0033819516 692686
1.9915724993,407000.44620213285 6925680.1747053144,405140.53768984287 6924692.09
83081609,403784.35439963144 6926261.3961154055)),((407484.79737720836 6926745.74
72904809,409732.18682955875 6926745.7472904809,409344.70588949829 6924323.991415
103,406922.95001412078 6924130.2509450726,407484.79737720836 6926745.7472904809)
))
```

Next utilize the ST_DissolvePoints function of Spatialite https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/xmlBlob/spatialite-sql-latest.html through SQLite SQL dialect of GDAL http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html. You must have GDAL that is compiled with new enough Spatialite because the ST_DissolvePoints function is pretty new.

```
ogrinfo multipolygon.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select dissolvepoints(geometry) from multipolygon"
INFO: Open of `multipolygon.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (403784.354400, 6924130.250945) - (409732.186830, 6926861.991572)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = dissolvepoints(geometry)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  MULTIPOINT (403784.35439963144 6926261.3961154055,405838.0033819516 6926861.99
15724993,407000.44620213285 6925680.1747053144,405140.53768984287 6924692.098308
1609,403784.35439963144 6926261.3961154055,407484.79737720836 6926745.7472904809
,409732.18682955875 6926745.7472904809,409344.70588949829 6924323.991415103,4069
22.95001412078 6924130.2509450726,407484.79737720836 6926745.7472904809)
```

I know that the result is not exactly what you aim at but perhaps you will find some use for the SQLite dialect in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going with what I know especially since it's working for me.  Hopefully someone finds your post useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# version, `ds` is a `OSGeo.OGR.Driver driver` and `layerIdX` is the layer you want:

```
OSGeo.OGR.Feature feature = null;
OSGeo.OGR.Geometry geo = null, ring = null;

double[] pointList = { 0, 0, 0 };

int layerIdX = 2;

OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(layerIdX);

if( geoType == "wkbMultiPolygon") 
{

    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfFeatures; ++i )
    {

        feature = layer.GetFeature(i);

        if( feature != null )
        {

            geo = feature.GetGeometryRef();

            for( int j = 0; j < geo.GetGeometryCount(); ++j )
            {

                var inGeo = geo.GetGeometryRef(j);

                for( int k = 0; k < inGeo.GetGeometryCount(); ++k )
                {

                    ring = inGeo.GetGeometryRef(k);

                    int pointCount = ring.GetPointCount();

                    for( int l = 0; l < pointCount; ++l )
                    {

                        ring.GetPoint( l, pointList );
                        // pointList[0] is the Longitude.
                        // pointList[1] is the Latitude.
                        // pointList[2] is the Altitude. 

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```